# convert key value pair in the payload to json object

Tags: jquery, json

Here is my json payload

```
"multiList": [
  {
    "Key": "my_key",
    "Value": this is my key
  },
  {
    "Key": "my_text_box",
    "Value": "This is my text box"
  },
```

]

How can I dynamically convert this using jquery

```
"multiList": [
  {
    "my_key" : "this is my key"
  },
  {
    "my_text_box": "This is my text box"
  },
```

]

Comment: Please note that you don't have JSON here, only plain JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example :

```
yourobj.multiList = yourobj.multiList.map(function(v) {
   var r = {};
   r[v.Key] = v.Value;
   return r;
});
```

If you want to support IE8, you'd have to [use a shim for map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or use `for` instead of `map` :

```
for (var i=0; i<yourobj.multiList.length; i++) {
    var v = yourobj.multiList[i];
    var r = {};
    r[v.Key] = v.Value;
    yourobj.multiList[i] = r;
}
```

Comment: how can I show[{ "my_key" : "this is my key"}, {"my_text_box": "This is my text box"} without showing the multilist